# TYPO3 - How can I display a Tag Search from tx_news into my Fluidtemplate?

Tags: tags, typo3, fluid, tx-news

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6.3`with the great News-Extension from Georg Ringer `news 4.1.0`.

I need the Tag-Search from `tx_news`as a Select-Box, so I include the Plugin and change the Template `/EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Extensions/News/Templates/Tag/List.html` from a ul/li-List to the selectbox. This part is working fine!

But I need this select-box not as a Content Element, I need it at my Footer-Navigation, which I made with TypoScript. How can I use the tx_news-Template (Tag/List.html) into my Footer-Partial?

Here's the screen:

[image: tag search news typo3 at template]

My version of the tag-list .. as a search box
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'v tried it like this ..

```
...
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tx_news_domain_model_tag
        select {
            selectFields = tx_news_domain_model_tag.title
            orderBy = tx_news_domain_model_tag.title asc
            ### pid folder 'tags'
            pidInList = 32
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            10 = TEXT
            10.field = uid
            10.wrap = <option value="|">
            10.wrap.insertData = 1

            20 = TEXT
            20.field = title
            20.wrap = |</option>
            20.wrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }

    20.wrap = <form method="get" action="/index.php"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="17" /><select name="tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]"><option value="" selected>Tag Suche</option>|</select></form>
...
```

and it works (thanks colin!)!
Also helpful: https://www.auxnet.de/typo3-datenbankabfragen-mit-typoscript/

Comment: .. a friend of mine. we talk about my problem .. there's no link to that solution.